# Dazed and Mesmerist Touch treatment

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, conditions

I was looking at the mesmerist occult class and they have an ability called Touch treatment, its like a paladins lay on hands for psychics that only cures conditions listed on the ability. One of the moderate ailments is dazed and dazed states that you **"dont take actions normally"** then says you take no actions for a round. The mesmerist is able to, as a swift action, remove ailments from itself.

So, my question is, can the mesmerist use a swift action to remove the dazed condition from itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer: No

The text is self-explanatory.

> **Dazed** 
>   The creature is unable to act normally. *A dazed creature can take no actions*, [...]

<sub>(emphasis mine. Also note that the wording is important. "Don't take actions normally" is unclear. "Can take no actions" is unambiguous.)</sub>

Nothing in Touch Treatment allows a Mesmerist to circumvent conditions to heal themself. You're dazed, you can not take actions; i.e. you can not take a swift action to cure yourself.